# Renaming files recursively in sh

Tags: shell-script, shell, rename, filenames, recursive

I use Synology as storage for films from CCTV cameras. After copying a file from the CCTV system to Synology, I convert it to the AVI format. So my files have names like this:

```
10.01.07-10.01.48[M][@0][0].dav.avi
```

I want to rename it recursively from the names like above for names like this:

```
10.01.07-10.01.48.avi
```

Please notice that each filename consist always the same part `[M][@0][0].dav.avi`

But the problem is that there is no `rename` command in Synology shell (it `sh` NOT `bash`)

I tried to use `find` command in many different syntaxes but without success. Can You help me to find out solution?

Answer (score 4):

You could do:

```
find . -name '*\[M]\[@0]\[0].dav.avi' -type f -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    echo mv "$file" "${file%"[M][@0][0].dav.avi"}.avi"
  done' sh {} +
```

(remove `echo` if that looks all right).

Or if you want to rename all the `.dav.avi` to `.avi`, but also remove a `[M][@0][0]` if there:

```
find . -name '*.dav.avi' -type f -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    new=${file%.*.*}
    new=${new%"[M][@0][0]"}.avi
    echo mv "$file" "$new"
  done' sh +
```

Those are POSIX syntax and also work with busybox utilities so should work on synology.

A few notes (based on observations of your own and other answers):

- the pattern passed to `find -name` must be quoted, otherwise it could be expanded by the shell.
- you can't use `xargs` on file names unless you can guarantee that those file names won't contain blanks or newlines or quotes or backslashes.
- [Use `printf` instead of `echo` to output arbitrary data](/q/65803).
- [Leaving a variable expansion unquoted in list context has a very special meaning](/q/68694). You don't want to do it here.
- The `.` character is a special regular expression operator, you need to escape it in regexps if you want it to be treated literally.
- [The syntax to read a line with `read` is `IFS= read -r line`](/q/209123), but again there's no guarantee that a file path be made of only one line.
- It's often better to do `(cd -P -- "$dir" && find . ... -exec)` than `find -- "$dir" ... -exec` because it avoids problems with `$dir` values that happen to be `find` predicates or start with `-` and because it shortens the file paths passed to `-exec` and thus allows to pass more.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick solution using `sed` to rename the files:

```
echo "10.01.07-10.01.48[M][@0][0].dav.avi" | sed 's/\[.*dav//'
10.01.07-10.01.48.avi
```

I know nothing about the Synology shell though, but I hope that `sed` is available!

Use (for example) in a loop:

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in *avi; do
    newName=$(echo "$file" | sed 's/\[.*dav//')
    mv -v "$file" "$newName" 
done
```

Before:

```
ls
09.01.07-13.11.48[M][@0][0].dav.avi
110.01.07-13.11.48[M][@0][0].dav.avi
12.01.07-13.11.48[M][@0][0].dav.avi
```

Running the script:

```
./renameAvi.sh 
”09.01.07-13.11.48[M][@0][0].dav.avi” -> ”09.01.07-13.11.48.avi”
”110.01.07-13.11.48[M][@0][0].dav.avi” -> ”110.01.07-13.11.48.avi”
”12.01.07-13.11.48[M][@0][0].dav.avi” -> ”12.01.07-13.11.48.avi”
```

After:

```
ls
09.01.07-13.11.48.avi   12.01.07-13.11.48.avi
110.01.07-13.11.48.avi
```

**Edit:**
If you want to use `find` *one* way to implement is like in this oneliner:

```
find . -name "*.avi" | while read fileName; do newName=$(echo "$fileName" | sed 's/\[.*dav//'); mv -v "$fileName" "$newName"; done
”./01.01.07-13.11.38[M][@0][0].dav.avi” -> ”./01.01.07-13.11.38.avi”
”./01.01.07-13.11.39[M][@0][0].dav.avi” -> ”./01.01.07-13.11.39.avi”
```

---

```
sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2

find --version
find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2
```

Answer (score 0):

For recursive files renaming you should use below command.

```
find . -name "*dav.avi" | while read fileName; do newName=$(echo "$fileName" | sed 's/\[.*dav//'); mv -v "$fileName" "$newName"; done
```

Change from the above script

(I could not add the comment above so adding answer here with small change in the script that maulinglawns has already mentioned)

- Use to search for *dav.avi as you will have many recursive files in your Synology storage, so once this files are renamed it should be done again.
- It is the very small change but will effect if your actual system is ~GBs of data files.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out solution. Renaming is done in two steps. It is because it is possible that other CCTV recorders will transmit files with different names but always in DAV format. So simply adding additional line similar to second one, will allow cooperation with other types of recorders:

```
find $katalog -type f -name *.dav.avi | sed -e "p;s/.dav.avi/\.avi/" | xargs -n2 mv 2>/dev/null
find $katalog -type f -name *.avi | sed -e "p;s/\[M\]\[@0\]\[0\].avi/\.avi/" | xargs -n2 mv 2>/dev/null
```